# Unable to configure kendo ui grid due to 'Renderer2'. error

Tags: angular, user-interface, kendo-ui

[image]
Hello i am trying to configure kendo ui grid into my angular2 cli project but its throw error during compilation time please some one tell me why i got renderer 2 error an my module .thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Renderer2` is found only in Angular 4.x and replaces the former `Renderer` used in Angular 2.

The Kendo Grid component was upgraded to Angular 4.x in version 0.23.0 on April 5th, 2017.

If your project uses Angular 2 then that's the source of the problem.